# Javascript and Jquery fire function when textbox changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I fire those functions when I click buttons? I need to run it when some text has change. but I have a button on my page.. when I type it changes but when I use buttons to change the value it doesnt fire the functions(codes)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var text1 = $(':text'),
    text2 = $(':text'),
    text3 = $(':text'),
    text4 = $(':text'),
    activeInput = text1;

activeInput.focus(); 

$(':text').on('focus', function(){

    activeInput = $(this);    
});

$(':button').on('click', function(){

    activeInput.val(activeInput.val()+ $(this).val());


 $('#dec').change(function(){
    fromdecimal();
 })

 $('#bin').bind('change click ', function(){
    frombinary();
 })

 $('#hex').bind('change click',function(){
    fromhexadecimal();
 })

 $('#oct').bind('change click',function(){
    fromoctal();
 })

  });  

});
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML for the JS provided above? If you want to trigger the input events when value is set on button click, you need to explicitly call `.trigger("<event>")` after setting the value of the input field.

Comment: can you provide an html?

Comment: <input  onclick = "clickdecimal();" onkeyup = "fromdecimal();" type = "text"  id = 'dec'/>Decimal<br/><br/>
 <input  onclick = "clickbinary();" onkeyup = "frombinary();" type = "text"  id = 'bin'/>Binary<br/><br/>
 <input  onclick = "clickhexadecimal();" onkeyup = "fromhexadecimal();" type = "text"  id = 'hex'/>Hexadecimal<br/><br/>
 <input  onclick = "clickoctal();" onkeyup = "fromoctal();" type = "text"  id = 'oct'/>Octal<br/><br/>

Comment: <button value = "0" id = 'btn0'> 0 </button><br>
  <button value = "1" id = 'btn1'> 1 </button>
  <button value = "2" id = 'btn2'> 2 </button>
  <button value = "3" id = 'btn3'> 3 </button><br>
  <button value = "4" id = 'btn4'> 4 </button>
  <button value = "5" id = 'btn5'> 5 </button>
  <button value = "6" id = 'btn6'> 6 </button><br>
  <button value = "7" id = 'btn7'> 7 </button>
  <button value = "8" id = 'btn8'> 8 </button>

Answer (score 0):

are you using :(colon) to select class?? if yes then you are doing wrong.

use . (dot) to select class like

```
var text = $('.text');
```

for any other issue , show your html code.

Comment: `:text` selector is to select all input fields of type `text`. OP has mentioned no problem about the selection.